# Show Out of Stock words On Category Pages and change color & font

Tags: magento-1.7

I've already configured to show product that is out of stock,

How Can I also show some texts under this product on category page? Like Pre-order now or Sold Out.  and Maybe also capable to change the color or font size of this word.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` to `/app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

and use below code to show out of stock message.

```
<?php if($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()){ ?>
    <p><a title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <p><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif} ?>
```

**custom_package** is the name of package folder and **custom_theme** is the name of theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the list.phtml file which appears in your category view. You can do it by switching template hints from backend (System/Configuration/Developer =switch to website or store view= /Debug tab)
2. Use following code:

   if ($product->isSalable()) {
    //Do your stuff
   }